# Dynamic Picklists of objects & its fields

Tags: visualforce, force.com

i have some requirement where i need 2 picklist on my VF page .
1st picklist contains Account,Contact,Lead & opportunity(objects).
based on this picklist value i want to display all fields of appropriate object.
for example if i select Account from 1st picklist then it should show all its fields into 2nd picklist.
please tell me how to do this & send some sample code.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the below code.

`Controller :`

```
public class objectController
{
    public Map <String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();

    public String selectedObject {get; set;}

    public String selectedField {get; set;}

    Public objectController()
    {   
        selectedObject = 'account';
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getObjectNames() 
    {
        List<SelectOption> objNames = new List<SelectOption>();
        List<String> entities = new List<String>(schemaMap.keySet());
        entities.sort();
        for(String name : entities)
        {
            objNames.add(new SelectOption(name,name));
        }
        return objNames;
     }

     public List<SelectOption> getObjectFields() 
     {
            Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
            Schema.SObjectType ObjectSchema = schemaMap.get(selectedObject);
            Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = ObjectSchema.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
            List<SelectOption> fieldNames = new List<SelectOption>();
            for (String fieldName: fieldMap.keySet()) 
            {  
                fieldNames.add(new SelectOption(fieldName,fieldName));
              //fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getLabel();//It provides to get the object fields label.
            }
            return fieldNames;
      }       
}
```

`Visualforce :`

```
<apex:page controller="objectController">
<apex:form > 
      <apex:pageBlock >
          <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">

              <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                  <apex:outputlabel value="Object Names :"/> 
                      <apex:actionRegion >      
                           <apex:selectList value="{!selectedObject}" size="1">
                                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!ObjectNames}"/>
                                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="myFields"/>
                            </apex:selectList>
                     </apex:actionRegion>                         
              </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

              <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                      <apex:outputlabel value="Field Names :"/>   
                      <apex:outputPanel id="myFields">   
                        <apex:actionRegion >  
                           <apex:selectList value="{!selectedField}" size="1">
                                <apex:selectOptions value="{!ObjectFields}"/>
                            </apex:selectList>
                        </apex:actionRegion>      
                     </apex:outputPanel>
              </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

          </apex:pageBlockSection>
      </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

The above code lists all the objects and the selected object is `Account`. And if you need only Account,Contact,Lead & opportunity object,you can hardcore the values in visualforce page/apex.

In VF you can do like this

```
<apex:selectList value="{!selectedObject}" size="1">                        
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="Account" itemLabel="Account" />
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="Contact" itemLabel="Contact"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="Lead" itemLabel="Lead" />
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="Opportunity" itemLabel="Opportunity"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

Hope it helps you.