# How to Populate text field values onto a lookup/picklist?

Tags: lookup, picklist, popup

**Subscribe system** object has a text field "**legacy ID**".  1 **account** can have many unique legacy ID. I have a new object **Sub Details** wherer I want to populate a picklist/lookup containing all legacy ID upon choosing 1 particular account, so that I can choose a particular legacy ID.

I have tried the following:

- List itemtried formula field, but can't because there are many legacy IDs for 1 account
- Tried lookup from Sub Details to Subscribe system.

How to proceed?

Comment: using a trigger?

Comment: How is Subscribe system and account is related ?

Answer (score 1):

Picklist ? is questionable because you will have to resort to 'Metadata API'. As for 'lookups' you can try using 'filtered lookup'

Refer to: http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_lookup_filters_defining.htm

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding the requirement, you want to

1. display all available legacy IDs, and allow the user to select one.
2. you would like the legacyIDs to display in a picklist for user to select
3. the set of legacy IDs are stored in a field on the Subscribe System object

If my understanding is correct, I see two approaches

1. use visual workflow and a [dynamic choice](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_designer_elements_screen_dynchoice.htm).  you can have the dynamic choice display the 'legacyId' field to the user to select.
2. use a visualforce page, and build a [dynamic picklist](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/48920/dynamic-picklists-of-objects-its-fields) using the describe system methods.

The visualforce page will be better if you can have multiple subscribe objects w/ the same legacy ID, as you should be able to remove duplicates when building the list.